# Como remover todas as ocorrências de "/" de uma string usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Olá, estou tendo problemas para aplicar um simples regex com Javascript. Assim:

```
var str = "/Date(1421287200000-0200)/";
console.log(str.replace('/\//g',''));             //não funciona, mesmo estando certo
console.log(str.replace('/[/]/g',''));            //não funciona, mesmo envolvendo "/"
console.log(str.replace('/','').replace('/','')); //funciona, mas não tem lógica
```

Como resolver este problema apenas com regex no Javascript?

**NOTA**: os dois primeiros exemplos foram testados no site Regexr como no exemplo aqui: http://regexr.com/3eo6t

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No javascript uma regex é delimitada `/` não precisa de aspas simples.

Mude:

```
console.log(str.replace('/\//g',''));
```

Para:

```
console.log(str.replace(/\//g,''));
```

Comment: ja estava respondendo a minha própria pergunta com isso mesmo rsrs, viajei aqui colocando como string um regex

Comment: @LeandroLUK depende da linguagem, algumas precisa das aspas e dos delimitadores.

Comment: foi por isso que eu errei, to aprendendo uma pancada de linguagem na faculdade, me embolei todo kkk

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é quebrar pela `/` e depois juntar.

```js
var str = "/Date(1421287200000-0200)/";
str = str.split("/").join("");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: mas ainda não é a melhor opção lógica. fazendo isso você executa 2 métodos, ao invés de apenas 1

Comment: É pra ser uma opção diferente do que já foi respondido, não a melhor, para você ou quer procurar saber que existe.